# Issue with Nested Resource Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, nested, controllers

I have been working with nested resources for the past two days, but I am not able to figure out this specific issue related to the nested resources and its corresponding controller. When you create a nested resource, is it convention to create a corresponding controller? What are best practices in dealing with a controller in this regard? Any tips and insight would be greatly appreciated!

My example:

### course.rb

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_students
  has_many :students, through: :course_students
end
```

### student.rb

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_students
  has_many :courses, through: :course_students
end
```

### course_student.rb

```
class CourseStudent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :student
end
```

### routes.rb

```
resources :courses do
  resources :students, controller: :courses_students
end
```

### courses_students_controller.rb

```
class CoursesStudentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_course_student, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
   @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
   @students = Student.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
   @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
   @student = Student.new
  end

  def create
   @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
   @student = Student.new(student_params)
   if @student.save
    @course.students << @student
    flash[:notice] = "Student form successfully submitted."
    redirect_to course_path(@course)
   else
    flash[:error] = "Unable to process your request."
    render :new
   end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
   Student.update(@student, student_params)
   redirect_to course_path(@course)
  end

  def destroy
   @student.destroy
   redirect_to course_path(@course)
  end

  private

  def set_course_student
   @student, @course = Student.find(params[:id]), Course.find(params[:course_id])
  end

  def student_params
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should work with courses_students as you are working with a separate model.

routes.rb

```
resources :courses
resources :students
resources :courses_students
```

controller

```
class CoursesStudentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
   @course_students = CourseStudent.all
  end

  def show
    @course_student = CourseStudent.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
   @course_student = Student.new(course_student_params)
  end

  def create
    @course_student = Student.new(course_student_params)
     if @student.save
    redirect_to @course_student
   else
    render 'new'
   end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
     @course_student = CourseStudent.find(params[:id])
     if @course_student.update(course_student_params)
       redirect_to @course_student
     else
    redirect_to @course_student
  end

  def destroy
    @course_student = CourseStudent.find(params[:id])
    @course_student.destroy
    redirect_to courses_students_path
  end

  private

  def course_student_params
    params.require(:course_student).permit(:course_id, :student_id)
  end
end
```